# FloatingLabel Text Filed place holder animation issues while using JVFloatLabeledTextField

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uistoryboard

I wanted a floating label text filed with underline or baseline for one of my iOS apps. I found that I can achieve that by making use of JVFloatLabeledTextField. So I drag & dropped some text fields to my storyboard and assigned JVFloatLabeledTextField as a class(custom) to those fields so that these text fields will be of type JVFloatLabeledTextField.

**ISSUE1**
In the below image the first part is what is showed after running the app. The issue here is when I start typing text in any of the textFields the place holder should animate upward but in my case the place holder is not showed/disappears as shown in the 2nd part of below image.When we tap on any other textField then the previously used textField palce holder is showed as shown in 3rd part of below image.

**ISSUE2**
keepBaseline = true, I have given this property to get the underline/baseline for the textFields, which I'm not getting.
I'm keeping all these text Fields in a stack view, will that cause any issue?

Programatically I haven't written any code for this.

**Find the image here**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2P3E.jpg]

Comment: I have normally used [SkyFloatingLabelTextField](https://github.com/Skyscanner/SkyFloatingLabelTextField) for achieve this effects

Comment: @chirag90 Will it give the baselines also or we need to add them separately?

Comment: what do you mean by baseline ?

Comment: @chirag90 A straight line under the text field.

Comment: it will provide it.

Comment: Ok Ty I'll try it out